# Proving discontinuity of a function defined by a double integral

Tags: calculus

Show that $$f(\alpha)=\int_{\alpha}^1 dx \int_{\alpha}^1\dfrac{(x-y)}{(x+y)^3} dy$$
is not continuous at $\alpha=0$.

I have found out the iterated integral at $\alpha=0$ which is $1/2$. But after that I got stuck for limit step.

Comment: @John Omelian I think that the ambiguity is fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

$$\int\dfrac{(x-y)}{(x+y)^3}\, dy=\frac{y}{(x+y)^2}$$
$$\int_{\alpha}^1\dfrac{(x-y)}{(x+y)^3} dy=\frac{1}{(x+1)^2}-\frac{\alpha }{(x+\alpha )^2}$$
$$\int\left( \frac{1}{(x+1)^2}-\frac{\alpha }{(x+\alpha )^2}\right)\, dx=\frac{\alpha }{x+\alpha }-\frac{1}{x+1}$$
$$I=\int_{\alpha+\epsilon}^1\left( \frac{1}{(x+1)^2}-\frac{\alpha }{(x+\alpha )^2}\right)\, dx=\frac{\alpha -1}{2 (\alpha +1)}-\frac{(\alpha -1) (\alpha +\epsilon )}{(\alpha
   +\epsilon +1) (2 \alpha +\epsilon )}$$ Now, using Taylor expansions around $\epsilon=0$
$$I=\frac{(\alpha -1)^2 }{4 \alpha  (\alpha +1)^2}\epsilon -\frac{\left(\alpha ^3-5
   \alpha ^2+3 \alpha +1\right) }{8 \alpha ^2 (\alpha
   +1)^3}\epsilon ^2+O\left(\epsilon ^3\right)$$